# Ruby on Rails: Gem Dependency Issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

I am trying to install the most recent version of **haml**, **simple_form**, and **devise** to my Ruby on Rails application, but I cannot seem to get them working with the Bundler tool. How should I proceed in order to get past the dependency issues?

This is the error raised by the Bundler tool:

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activemodel":

```
  In snapshot (Gemfile.lock):
    activemodel (= 5.1.1)

  In Gemfile:
    rails (~> 5.1.1) was resolved to 5.1.1, which depends on
      activemodel (= 5.1.1)

    rails (~> 5.1.1) was resolved to 5.1.1, which depends on
      activemodel (= 5.1.1)

    simple_form (~> 3.4) was resolved to 3.4.0, which depends on
      activemodel (< 5.1, > 4)

    web-console (>= 3.3.0) was resolved to 3.5.1, which depends on
      activemodel (>= 5.0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, `simple_form` is not compatible yet with Rails 5.1 as you can see from this commit https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/commit/8d15b7ebc8096348b611e9f2905a2576a5bce508

You'll either have to wait for a new version of simple_form or use an earlier version.

Answer (score 1):

Run bundle update with `--conservative` key, it does not try to update rails dependencies, these gems have.

```
bundle update haml simple_form devise --conservative
```

Answer (score -1):

If you may, try using rails version 4.2.4
This will allow  you to use 'simple_form' and 'nested_form' if needed.